# WPF overlap textblocks

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi I have 3 textblocks in which when i click any of three buttons, one of the texblocks will show and the other 2 will hide. so far i can do the click and show the relative textblock, but the 3 textblocks do not show and hide at the same position? how do i position them at the same  place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are using `Btn.Visibility="Hidden"`. Use `Btn.Visibility="Collapsed"`.

Answer (score 0):

Overlap them by throwing them all into the same grid:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Name="text1" Text="First Text" />
    <TextBlock Name="text2" Text="Second Text" />
    <TextBlock Name="text3" Text="Third Text" />
</Grid>
```

Elements in the same row/column in a grid (0 by default, as in the example above) will overlap.